# Is using timers/signals in c static libraries bad practice?

Tags: c, linux, timer, signals

I'm building two static c libraries.  Each of the libraries have a routine that needs to run once every second after calling mylib_init();

I implemented this in each library using setitimer, which uses the ITIMER_REAL resource and the SIGALRM signal.

```
void Start1msTimer()
{
    struct itimerval new;
    memset(&new,0, sizeof(new));

    new.it_interval.tv_sec=1;
    new.it_value.tv_sec=1;

    signal (SIGALRM, OneSecTimeout);
    setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, &new,NULL);
}
```

Ok so far so good everything was working.

Now I'm building a sample application that uses both of these libraries, and conflicts are arising. I have realized an application can only have one handler for each signal, and ITIMER_REAL can only be used for one timer, not both.  So obviously things are not working now.

What would be a better way for me to implement the timing in each of my libraries?

In general, is it a bad idea to have any signal handlers inside of a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use threads + a syncronization method. Instead of writing a signal handler, you write a thread. Using a semaphore, you can even run your event thread either on timeout or on demand (ie the app calls a library function that post the semaphore).

Comment: Thanks I ended up doing something like this but without semaphores. I just created threads that called usleep() for the amount of time I wanted to wait between invocations.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's a very bad idea to "use up" application-level resources in a library, since the application developer using the library won't get a say in how the resources should be allocated.

And, as you discovered, you get interoperability problems when multiple libraries want to own the same resource.

One way to fix this is to factor out the requirement, have a function `mylib_update()` and document that the application must call it once a second. That leaves the question of how to implement such a timer-based updating to the application, where it belongs.

Comment: Thanks I guess I have a lot of refactoring to do.